# Find the Expectation Value of Basis States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Recently, I have picked up a Quantum Computing class. We have been asked to find the expectation value of $X$ tensor $Z$ and $H$ tensor $H$

$$  (|00>+|11>)/\sqrt(2); \qquad (|00>-|11>)/\sqrt(2);  \qquad(|01>+|10>)/\sqrt(2);  \qquad(|01>-|10>)/\sqrt(2); $$

I have found some stuff on the expectation value and it looks like a big integral that I have not yet learned about. I know the expected value from Probability, but I am pretty sure I am looking at different things. If someone could guide me or direct me to a place that first explains what is the expectation value and then how to apply the operator tensor operator to the basis states, that would be great. I am comfortable working in vectors for most of these problems. Thank you.

Comment: Where are the tensors?

Comment: its x with a circle outside of it. I thought it was \oprod. But it is the usually notation of tensors when thinking with vectors

Comment: I did not ask what $\otimes$ was. (BTW: \otimes) I don't see the observables. I see only states. As far as I know: if you want the expectation then you need the values and the probabilities. How do I get the probabilities if I don't know the observables -- only the states?